# Sending form data to one page, then another?

Tags: php, html

I'm having a bit of trouble with this one, as basic as it may be. I have a simple form with name, email, comments, etc. that outputs itself to one php page, but I want to have a link that sends it to a second page, for example:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" size="20" />
```

Goes to a second page (second.php) with this code and prints it just fine:

```
print "<div>Thank you, $name.</p></div>";
```

But if I try to send $name to a third page (third.php) using similar code it shows up like this:

```
Thank you, $name.
```

With the actual variable and not what was stored in $name.

I feel like I'm missing one tiny little thing but I'm not sure what it is. I used this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

To bring it to second.php and this to bring it to third.php:

```
print 'Click <a href="third.php? name=' . $name . '">here</a> to proceed.';
```

Just to see if it would get the same information from second.php, but I don't think it works that way. Is there something else I should be doing on the third page? I have a feeling it's something incredibly insignificant but as I'm learning, I just can't quite get a grasp on it.

Comment: http is stateless, there is no reason page3 should get the same data as page 2, you post to page 2 not page 3 - see sessions, if you want to carry the variable on

Comment: If you are passing data via the query string it should work fine.  It looks like variable replacement is not occuring.  What is the content of third.php? Are you using single quotes instead of double quotes('Thank you $name' vs "thank you $name")?  PHP will not automatically perform variable replacement when a variable is used inside single quotes.

Comment: Using your method you need to use `$name = $_GET['name']` not `$name = $_POST['name']` on the third page.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, I'm currently playing around with it to see if I can get it working.

Comment: I figured out the problem wasn't my method of getting the information from one page to another but rather the use of single quotes rather than double quotes in my print command. Strange, but I'm starting to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

when you declare

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

you can use in a header to pass this variable

```
if(isset($_POST['btnname']))
{
header('Location: second.php?name='.$name);
}
```

The in your second php

you can get it by this way

```
 Thank you, <php echo $_GET['name']; ?>
```

Or if you want it to be available to all pages use session

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
```

=D

Answer (score 0):

you can try it using a hidden input

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<? echo $name; ?>" size="20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Websites are stateless, which means that the variables only last for a few seconds on the server, then the html is rendered, and sent to the clients browser. The server memory is then freed up to serve other clients.

You have a few options: 
1) Using a hidden form field and printing (with php) their name to the hidden form field so when they post again it gets saved (if they post again).
2) Sessions 
3) cookies 
4) Print it out in the url (i.e. page.php?name=".$name; )

It all depends on how you get to your third page (From a link? A form? A php redirect?)

Comment: I'm using method 4. Let me edit that above so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Using a php redirect seems to be the best method but I just can't seem to get away from the problem I had before where it just says $name instead of what was sent before. Back to the drawing board I suppose...

Comment: (third.php? name=) why the space between the ? and name?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the name in the second page and again set the $_GET variable before the third page is called. This is because the variables are only valid for that particular request and they need to be set again when another request is made.